Labels not displaying correctly with tkinter (wordle duplicate)
first of all I am a beginner and I am very new at this so please don't be too harsh even if the mistakes are really dumb or avoidable...
With that said, I have an assignment in python for which I have to make wordle in python. I did manage to make my program work in "simple" python, but I've been trying to make it work with tkinter in order to have a nice interface. It's the first time I'm trying tkinter.
Now the problem I have is that I've been trying to make it so that the labels associated with each letter in the guess become yellow if the letter is misplaced, gray if it isn't present in the word to guess and green if the letter is correctly placed. The way I'm checking the placement of the letters is by storing the placements in a "result" variable which looks like this by default : xxxxxx and my code changes x with o with a first for loop for the correct placements and with a second for loop it adds the +s that are missing. I'm doing it that way because it accounts for duplicate letters.
My idea was to take the resulting "result" variable (for example lets say "xxo+xx" and compare it to the letters in my variable "proposition" so that if there's a x in result, the label associated to that letter is gray, if there's a o, the label is green, and if there's a + the label is yellow.
enter image description here
When I try to test the program I have this : (these are french words)
I don't know why but when I enter "voisin" the second i just vanishes and the labels are changing only for the last letter and the N goes from yellow to gray
I know that the problem must lie in the way I handle the labels, the result variable, the for loops and the order of the elements in my code but I cannot for the life of me find the way, I could settle for the program I already managed to complete but I really want this simple thing to work...
Heres the code :
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random 

lexique = []
def lire_lexique(fichier) :
    with open(fichier, mode="r",encoding='utf-8') as flux:
        global lexique
        for ligne in flux:
            lexique.append(ligne.strip("\n"))
        return lexique
lire_lexique("lexique.txt")
secret = str(random.choice(lexique))
secretresult = secret

root = Tk()

root.title("Wordle")


green = "#6ca965"
yellow = "#c8b653"
gray = "#787c7f"
black = "#000000"
white = "#FFFFFF"

root.config(bg=black)

guessnum = 1

wordInput = Entry(root)
wordInput.grid(row=999, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=3)


def getGuess():

    global secret
    proposition = wordInput.get()

    global guessnum
    guessnum += 1
    
    if guessnum <= 6:
        if proposition not in lexique :
            messagebox.showerror("pas dans le lexique","ce mot n'est pas dans le lexique, veuillez réessayer")
        if proposition in lexique and len(proposition) == 6:    
            
            if secret == proposition: 
                messagebox.showinfo("correct!", f"correct! the word was {secret.title()}")
                
            for letter in proposition :  
                    label = Label(root, text=letter.upper())
                    label.grid(row=guessnum, column=proposition.index(letter), padx=10, pady=10)      
            else: 
                result = ["x"] * 6  

                for index, (letter, letter2) in enumerate(zip(proposition, secret)):   
                    if letter == letter2:
                        result[index] = "o" 
                        secret = secret.replace(letter, "x", 1)
                for index, (letter, letter2) in enumerate(zip(proposition, secret)):
                    if letter in secret and  result[index] == "x":
                        result[index] = "+"
                        secret = secret.replace(letter, "x", 1)
        
                for char in result : 
                    if char == "+" :
                        label.config(bg=black, fg=yellow)
                    elif char == "x" :
                        label.config(bg=black, fg=gray)
                    elif char == "o":
                        label.config(bg=black, fg=green) 

        elif len(proposition) < 6 or len(proposition) > 6:
            messagebox.showerror("Veuillez entrer un mot de 6 lettres", "Le mot doit être un mot de 6 lettres")
    
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("C'est perdu", f"C'est perdu ! Le mot était {secretresult}")


wordGuessButton = Button(root, text="Guess", command=getGuess)
wordGuessButton.grid(row=999, column=3, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()


All of your label.config() calls are outside the loop that iterates label - so they will only apply to the last label.

I had some difficulty understanding your problem (English to French you know), so I recoded your script until it worked, tell me if that's what you needed.
Here are the points I noted:

There were a lot of loops, everything can be done in one loop
I noticed that parts of the script were way too complex for nothing, this can happen at the beginning
It's possible that I didn't understand anything, and if that's the case, I'm sorry!

I believe the result variable is not useful for what you are trying to do.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random 

lexique = []
def lire_lexique(fichier) :
    with open(fichier, mode="r",encoding='utf-8') as flux:
        global lexique
        for ligne in flux:
            lexique.append(ligne.strip("\n"))
        return lexique
lire_lexique("lexique.txt")
secret = str(random.choice(lexique))
secretresult = secret

root = Tk()

root.title("Wordle")


green = "#6ca965"
yellow = "#c8b653"
gray = "#787c7f"
black = "#000000"
white = "#FFFFFF"

root.config(bg=black)
root.geometry("400x250")

guessnum = 1

wordInput = Entry(root)
wordInput.grid(row=999, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=3)


def getGuess():

    global secret
    proposition = wordInput.get()

    global guessnum
    guessnum += 1
    
    if guessnum <= 6:
        if proposition not in lexique :
            messagebox.showerror("pas dans le lexique","ce mot n'est pas dans le lexique, veuillez réessayer")
        if proposition in lexique and len(proposition) == 6:    
            
            if secret == proposition: 
                messagebox.showinfo("correct!", f"correct! the word was {secret.title()}")
            else: 
                for i in range(6):  
                    label = Label(root, text=proposition[i].upper())
                    label.grid(row=guessnum, column=i, padx=10, pady=10)    
                
                    if secret[i] == proposition[i]:
                        label.config(bg=black, fg=green) 
                    elif proposition[i] in secret:
                        label.config(bg=black, fg=yellow)
                    else:
                        label.config(bg=black, fg=gray)
                        
        elif len(proposition) < 6 or len(proposition) > 6:
            messagebox.showerror("Veuillez entrer un mot de 6 lettres", "Le mot doit être un mot de 6 lettres")
    
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("C'est perdu", f"C'est perdu ! Le mot était {secretresult}")


wordGuessButton = Button(root, text="Guess", command=getGuess)
wordGuessButton.grid(row=999, column=3, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()

